# Mean stack 2 implementation

Tags: mean-stack, mean.io

I want to implement a mean stack with angular 2 and node 6, but I got stuck in finding a tutorial.

There is a way of installing a MEAN stack manually or with some starter kit like mean.io?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to implement a MEAN Stack, basic understanding of each component is needed.

- MongoDB : NoSql Database
- Express.js : Nodejs library for web applications.
- Angular : MVC framework for front End.
- Node.js : Event driven (Non blocking I/O) Server side execution environment.

Advantage : MEAN applications can be written in one language for both server-side and client-side execution environments. Hence, Javascript developers can work full stack.

Link for a free tutorial to get you moving : [Mean Stack on EdX](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-mongodb-using-mean-stack-mongodbx-m101x-0)